# Отправка sms на несколько номеров

Tags: android

Добрый день!
Не получается отправить смс на несколько номеров в цикле:

```
for(int i=0; i<arList.size(); i++)
 {
   SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
   sms.sendTextMessage(smsNum[i], null, smsText, null, null);
 }
```

Подозреваю что просто цикл отрабатывает гораздо быстрее чем отправляется смс, подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить эту задачу
Пробовал еще так: [Unable to send sms using SMSManager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998655/unable-to-send-sms-using-smsmanager-in-android), но безуспешно.
Корректно ли будет если я отправлять смс буду в Runnable. К примеру отправил первое смс в BroadcastReceiver увидел что оно отправлено и затем в Runnable отправил следующее смс и т.д.?
Спасибо!

Comment: у метода sendTextMessage() 4ым параметром идёт PendingIntent, вызывающийся после отправки смс. Как вариант - организуйте Activity для отправки sms, в intent засовывайте номер и текст смс, в Activity доставайте их, формируйте intent со следующим номером и вызывайте sendTextMessage. Сам не пробовал, но по логике вещей должно сработать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил следующим образом: отправлял в runnable в broadcastreceiver получал результат отправки и после этого снова отправлял в runnable и т.д. Благодарю за советы.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, в манифест надо добавить следующее разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Во-вторых, смс-сообщение шлется не менее 1-2секунды, поэтому вам надо делать паузу между посылкой.
И наконец в-третьих: если вообще не посылается смс-сообщение, то надо перенастроить настройки смс в меню устройства.

Comment: 1-2 секунды - это сильно... Программирование все таки точная наука. Здесь надо не так - подумайте на досуге :)